# arity mismatch; the expected number of arguments does not match the given number expected: 1 given: 2

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I am learning racket with book:SICP.
In chapter 2 (picture language). There's Image like this. [George.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7YHK.png).

And I am trying to make this *'George.img'* with DrRacket but in my code there's error like below.

```
...sn-less-unit.rkt:675:8: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:
   '(182.5 . 0)
   '(255.49999999999997 . 365.0)
```

I once asked help for my problem and I solved. But I got this new problem.
This is the code that matters.

```
; make-picture
(define (make-picture segment-list)   
 (lambda (rect)     
  (for-each     
   (lambda (segment)   
     (draw-line ((frame-coord-map rect) (start-segment segment))   ;draw-line is problem...
                ((frame-coord-map rect) (end-segment segment))))      
   segment-list)))
```

According to my understanding, I need to give 1 argumets to `draw-line` procedure.
But in my book:SICP, I can see there's 2 arguments.
So should I make another procedure `draw-line`?

Just in case, I'll upload my full code. If someone can help me, please.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wJdYQDNy93Ue4AdBatrawfMbMOSTcZPK/view?usp=sharing

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you're using Racket you might conisder using the SICP Pict language: https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/SICP_Picture_Language.html  I'm not very familiar with it - I don't think it supports `draw-line` but looks like it has the higher level procedure `segments->painter`

Comment: There's also the [racket/draw](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/index.html) library built on top of Cario.

Comment: As for pict, @codybartfast I would recommend [this version](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/index.html) as it's built on top of racket/draw, unless, like the OP they are using SICP. Just saw that.